# I import a project using Grails 2.2.1 and tried to use it in a 2.1.1 Grails app. It failed with an error

Tags: grails

When i imported a project of version 2.2.1 in grails 2.1.1 it shows me this error, could anyone suggest me a solution for this

Error Error executing script Compile:

> loader constraint violation: when resolving overridden method
>   "org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2$RootHandler.setDocumentLocator(Lorg/xml/sax/Locator;)V"
>   the class loader (instance of
>   org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/support/GrailsRootLoader) of the
>   current class, org/apache/tools/ant/helper/ProjectHelper2$RootHandler,
>   and its superclass loader (instance of ), have different
>   Class objects for the type org/xml/sax/Locator used in the signature

Answer (score 2):

That particular error is usually due to something that has a transitive dependency on `xml-apis` (which has not been necessary since Java 5), and can be fixed by looking at the results of `grails dependency-report` and adding the relevant `excludes` to your BuildConfig dependencies.

Comment: when i command this dependency-report in grails it shows the same error, i was not able to see that result.